# how to calculate the number to increment the variable

Tags: javascript

How can I calculate the missing number, so that when I add it to a certain variable the result will be equal to or greater than the other variable.

- Promoter: 10
- Detractor: 2
- Total: 12
- Average: 66.67
- Target: 75
- You need ??? Promoters to reach your Target.

I want to find how many Promoters I need if the Average is less than the Target. How can I calculate the missing number so that when I add it to the Promoter the results of the Average is equal to or greater than the Target.

Thank You!

```
function missingNum() {

var xPromoter = '';
var x = 10;
var y = 2;
var target = 75;
var z = x + y;
var v = ((x - y) / z) * 100;

    average = Math.round(v * 100) / 100;

        if (average<target) //how to increment x so that average => target

            document.write("Promoter:" + "\n" + x + "<br>");

            document.write("Detractor:" + "\n" + y + "<br>" ); 

            document.write("Total:" + "\n" + z + "<br>" );

            document.write("Average:" + "\n" + average + "<br>" );

            document.write("Target:" + "\n" + target + "<br>" );

            document.write("You need " + "\n" + xPromoter + "Promoters to reach your Target." );

}
```

Comment: Firstly, don't declare xPromoter as a `String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always make a simple function.. however a calculation might be better..

```
function calculateNeededPromoters (promo, detrac) {
    var percentage = 0.00;
    var currentPromo = promo;
    while (percentage < 75) {
        currentPromo++;

        var total = currentPromo + detrac;
        var v = ((currentPromo - detrac) / total) * 100;
        percentage = Math.round(v * 100) / 100;
    }
    return currentPromo;
}
```

Comment: A calculation would be much better than all this needless looping. It's a one-line math formula (see the other two answers).

Comment: That's what I said :] I quote: "however a calculation might be better..".. I've simply given an alternative for people like me.. who aren't that good at (basic) algebra :]

Comment: You are right I'm not that good in algebra. I tried adding a new variable but I can't get the correct algebraic equation to get it work. But I tried playing with your inputs and I got the results I need. Please check if the script is correct. Thanks!

Comment: `var promo = 5;
     var detrac = 3;
     var neut = 5;
     var tar = 46;

     var percentage = 0.00;
     var currentPromo = promo;
        while (percentage < tar) { currentPromo++; `
  
  var total = currentPromo + detrac + neut; 
  var ave = ((currentPromo - detrac) / total) * 100; percentage = Math.round(ave * 100) / 100; } 
  
  var neededPromo = currentPromo - promo;`

Answer (score 1):

Forget looping and do some math! Doing some algebra, the formula for needed promoters, given the target and current number of detractors and promoters, is:

```
promotersNeeded = (detractors * (target + 100) / (100 - target)) - promoters
```

So in your example,

```
promotersNeeded = 2 * (75 + 100) / (100 - 75) - 10
```

which comes out to 4.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple problem of algebra.

Average = ((Promoters - Detractors) / Total) * 100

Let `fp` be the final number of promotors you're looking for
Let `d` be the current number of Detractors
Let `t` be your target Average

1. The formula using these variable to find your target starts as such:
   ((fp - d) / (fp + d)) * 100 = t
2. Divide by 100
   (fp - d) / (fp + d) = t / 100
3. Multiply both sides by (fp + d)
   fp - d = (t / 100) * (fp + d)
4. Distribute t / 100
   fp - d = (t / 100) * fp + (t / 100) * d
5. Add d to both sides
   fp = (t / 100) * fp + (t / 100) * d + d
6. Subtract (t / 100) * x from both sides
   fp - (t / 100) * fp = (t / 100) * d + d
7. Simplify the lefthand side
   (1 - t / 100) * fp = (t / 100) * d + d
8. You want to have only fp on the lefthand side, so divide both sides by (1 - t / 100)
   fp = ((t / 100) * d + d) / (1 - t / 100)
   This is the formula you will use to find the total number of promotors you need

Now just plug in the numbers for `t` and `d` and solve for `x`
`fp = ((75 / 100) * 2 + 2) / (1 - 75 / 100)`

Writing this all out so you can see the final result:
`fp = (.75 * 2 + 2) / (1 - .75)`
`fp = (1.5 + 2) / .25`
`fp = 3.5 / .25`
`fp = 14`

Using the variables in your program

```
var fp = ((target / 100) * y + y) / (1 - target / 100);
xPromoter = fp - x;
```